# Python prints memory address instead of a list when using __repr__ __str__?

Tags: python, string, memory, printing, repr

I'm tasked to make a "Set" class that contains the variable self.list and be able to print and str() the object by writing the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods. A second file (driver1.py), a "driver file" creates a Set object and attempts to call print(str(set_object)) and print(set_object) but both calls only print a memory address, `Set.Set instance at 0x1033d1488>` or some other location. How do I change this? I want it to print out the contents of the set_object in the form `{1,2,3}`

Here is my code in it's entirety after updating indentation.

class Set:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.list = []

def add_element(self, integer):
    if integer not in self.list:
        self.list.append(integer)

def remove_element(self, integer):
    while integer in self.list: self.list.remove(integer)

def remove_all(self):
    self.list = []

def has_element(self, x):
    while x in self.list: return True
    return False
#probably doesnt work, __repr__
def __repr__(self):
    if self.list.len == 0:
        return "{}"
    return "{"+", ".join(str(e) for e in self.list) +"}"
#Same as above, probably doesnt work
def __str__(self):
    if len(self.list) == 0:
        return "{}"
    return "{"+", ".join(str(e) for e in self.list) +"}"

def __add__(self, other):
    counter = 0
    while counter <= len(other.list):
        if other.list[counter] not in self.list:
            self.list.append(other.list[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
```

Why do I get the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Set import *
  File "/Users/josh/Documents/Set.py", line 23
    return "{"+", ".join(str(e) for e in self.list) +"}"
                                                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Your code does not even run for me, how are you creating an instance?

Comment: To post your code properly here it needs to be indented by *another* 4 spaces; that's why `class Set:` isn't displayed in the code block. BTW, you can change `while` to `if` in your `remove_element` and `has_element` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. Don't do that; this is what happens when you do. Python thinks some of your methods are actually internal to some of your other methods, so the `Set` class doesn't actually have `__str__` or `__repr__` methods.

Fix your indentation, and your problem will go away. To avoid such problems in the future, turn on "show whitespace" in your editor, and try running Python with the `-tt` command line option if you think you might be seeing tab-related bugs.

Comment: @quintillion: You probably haven't fixed your indentation properly. Go through it again, and you'll likely find something you missed.

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem at:

```
if self.list.len == 0:
```

you probably meant to do:

```
if len(self.list) == 0:
```

Once this issue is fixed, the code works:

```
s = Set()
s.add_element(1)
s.add_element(1)
s.add_element(2)
s.add_element(3)
print s  # prints {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Or maybe `if self.list.__len__() == 0`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, that should work too (though it's ugly :)

Comment: Yep, I think that is what probably confused the OP though. I would still love to know how the OP got the code to run

Comment: Well I'm using xcode and the indentation settings were pretty weird so I altered them. Evidently I tabs are bad, and I did not know that. Maybe xcode somehow operates around it if it was changed in the settings? Regardless, I replaced all tab characters with 4 spaces and updated the original code. It might work for you, now.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham assuming no indentation errors (after using pycharm auto-indent for instance), and fixing the problem I mentioned above, it seems the code works - though I have to admit that I didn't test each and every function.

Comment: @alfasin did you happen to test the str or repr functions? I cannot get past the unindent errors at this point to figure out if they even work.

Comment: @quintillion yes - both functions are working for me - it's only a matter of indentation + the issue I mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: @quintillion, it worked fine for me once I used `if self.list.__len__() `, what I meant was how did it work at all for you to get any output as your code was invalid syntactically.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have no idea. It just worked with xcode, I don't know why. I am not familiar with either xcode or python so I really don't know what to say, sorry! But you're right, it does seem rather strange that it even ran for me in the first place.